# Crystal Reports Question: Can I count the number of times an instance occurs in a free text field?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to count the number of times a particular string of text occurs in a free-text field. Basically, the field could have 111, 222, 333, 111, 333, etc and I want to count how many times 111, 222, and 333 occur in the text field, respectively, so I can multiply those codes by a particular fee. I could do this fairly easily if each field only had one code, but there could be up to twenty codes in a given field so I need to find a new way to count them.
Thanks in advance!

So far I have tried a three part formula but couldn't get the code to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Store the target matches in an array.
Loop through the array and, for each target match, use an inner loop to count the number of matches.

Use InStr(start, str1, str2, compare) in the inner loop because the start argument allows you to target the remaining text after each match.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Will this work if all the values are stored in the same text field? I.e., not discrete entries? For instance, the field type is VARCHAR2(4000) and the user can type in multiple codes in the same entry. Thanks again for your assistance; I haven't used arrays in this capacity before and look forward to learning more.

Comment: yes, that was the assumed scenario. InStr() function would refer to the text column.